# How can I count users that generate events within a certain period of time with Kafka Streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have streaming events which has user-id in it. I want to count how many distinct user generate an event within certain of time. However, I am beginner in Kafka and I cannot cope with the problem.

Example events in 1 minutes;

```
{"event_name": "viewProduct", "user_id": "12"}
{"event_name": "viewProductDetails", "user_id": "23"}
{"event_name": "viewProductComments", "user_id": "12"}
{"event_name": "viewProduct", "user_id": "23"}
{"event_name": "viewProductComments", "user_id": "32"}
```

My code should generate there are 3 active users according to the events above.

My approach is as follows, however this solution cannot eliminate multiple event from same user and count the same user multiple times.

```
builder.stream("orders") // read from orders toic
                .mapValues(v -> { // get user_id via json parser
                    JsonNode jsonNode = null;
                    try {
                        jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree((String) v);
                        return jsonNode.get("user_id").asText();
                    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                        return "";
                    })
                .selectKey((k, v) -> "1") // put same key to every user_id
                .groupByKey()
                .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(1))) // use time windows
                .count() // count values
```

Comment: Why are you setting the same key ("1") on all the records?

Comment: I want to group all data under the same key and count easily. However, I know my approach is not good and not figure out the problem.

Comment: By the way, you wouldn't need the ObjectMapper if you used JSONSerde for the value deserializer

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something here by why don't you just do:

```
.selectKey((k, v) -> v)
```

That will group the record by value, which you previously populated with `user_id`.